# Why am I blacklisted in UAE?

Tags: visa-refusals, uae

I was a previous resident of Abu Dhabi for almost 2 years and I had a valid work permit. I resigned from my job voluntarily and returned to my home country without any problem. Two years after, I applied for a tourist visa to go to Dubai and boom, rejected! I applied again for three more times with some timeframe in between, and all were rejected.

During my stay, I've never broken any law or done anything illegal. It is worth mentioning that some people told me that you're blacklisted because you canceled your own work permit. It is really frustrating to be blacklisted for no apparent or legit reason.

Comment: Obviously, only the UAE can tell you why they blacklist you. Although I understand your frustration, there is nothing anyone here can do to help you.

Comment: Likely because you worked there before, they are considering you a high risk for seeking work on a tourist visa.

Comment: Voted to reopen. While the exact reason may be known by the UAE, it is another thing that they will tell the truth. I think it is not correct that "nothing anyone here can do to help you", I believe other people here may have experienced the same problem and have found out (even by a hunch) what happened.